# Samsung galaxy book 2 pro support

Tags: samsung, compatibility

Is Ubuntu now supported on samsung galaxy book 2 pro ?

2 months back I installed; Following drivers were missing

1. Sound Driver (No audio when watching video)
2. Display Driver (Could not tune brightness. stayed at max level)
3. Intel Iris Xeon Graphics driver
4. Fingerprint Sensor

Could be more. I uninstalled after some time and went back to windows.

Comment: Wrong place to ask and wrong way to ask (these are yes/no questions). We do not provide hardware recommendations and if hardware does not work someone needs to file bugreports. Those are done on bugzilla, github or launchpad not on askubuntu. Mind that after a google search I came to the conclusion that some of these have been working well over a YEAR ago.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Comment: @Rinzwind this laptop came in march 2022. How can it be working well year ago ?

Comment: The model is not important, what is inside it is. Linux works with GENERIC drivers so when a chipset is used and is supported all models in that line will work too. Might lack a new feature until an update is released but install and work it wil

Comment: Updated information about this notebook could be found here [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/GalaxyBook/comments/uxpbyz/installing_linux_on_gbp2_360_guide/)

Answer (score 0):

Not working on this end: Fresh install of Kubuntu 22.10 this week on mine, and no sound / brightness control.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1272996)